# I want to create a new column with ages according to birth dates but I'm not able to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, python-datetime

I have a df with date of birth and I want to add another column with age. I want to understand what the problem is with this iteration I made. Why does this code put the age of the last user on every line instead of putting the age of each user?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame(['9/26/1987 12:00:00 AM',
                   '9/21/1989 12:00:00 AM',
                   '2/23/1980 12:00:00 AM',
                   '7/19/1988 12:00:00 AM',
                   '1/23/1984 12:00:00 AM'], columns=['dob'])

df['Age'] = ""
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.replace(df.iloc[i,1], dt.date.today().year - dt.datetime.strptime(df.iloc[i,0], "%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p").year, inplace = True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     dob  Age
0  9/26/1987 12:00:00 AM   38
1  9/21/1989 12:00:00 AM   38
2  2/23/1980 12:00:00 AM   38
3  7/19/1988 12:00:00 AM   38
4  1/23/1984 12:00:00 AM   38
```

Answer (score 0):

when using Pandas your last resort should be to use loops: vectorization is the purpose of the module.  That being said:

I'm going to assume your dob column is already in a datetime format.  if not just call something like:

```
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'])
```

Then get today's date from the datetime module and convert it to a type Pandas can handle,

```
from datetime import date
df['Age'] = (pd.to_datetime(date.today()) -  df['dob']).dt.days
```

calling df['Age'] = ... creates a new column, whereas df['dob'] references the column that is already available.  Pandas is smart enough to know that you want to take the individual date of today and subtract it from every item in the 'dob' column.  No need to run a loop since they are very slow in Python.

You don't have to use ".dt.days" at the end if you want the exact time between today and dob.